# Callback for the setSelection function of VisJS Timeline

Tags: javascript, timeline, vis.js

Is it possible to add callback to the `setSelection` function of VisJS Timeline?

The reason - I want to add specific actions for the element when Timeline chart select this element for me.

As example - I want to bind some js function to the `.vis-item` block when it appears (shows) on chart.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Fond solution with the `timeline.moveTo` function which has callback.